# Create word bubbles as buttons in HTML/CSS/JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create multiple bubbled words as buttons!

what is the best way to approach the design below using CSS or any JS library?

[image: ss]

There can be many buttons (depends on the data from DB)

What I've tried:

```css
#tagsContainer {
  float: left;
  width: 25vw;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#tags {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: space-between;
  grid-gap: 8px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(30%, 1fr));
}

#tag {
  background-color: #2F3841;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<div id="tagsContainer">
  <h3 id="tagsTitle">TOP TAGS</h3>
  <div id="tags">
    <div id="tag">
      <h4 id="tagTitle">Flutter</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="tag">
      <h4 id="tagTitle">Deep Learning</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="tag">
      <h4 id="tagTitle">Machine Learning</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is when using **grid layout** all the columns would be same in size!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use display:inline-block and style your container as you want.
P.s. you have the same id multiple times, use class instead because id must be unique

```css
#tagsContainer {
  /*float: left; REMOVE IT!!!*/
  width: 25vw;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#tags {
  /* NOT NECESSARY
  display: grid;
  justify-content: space-between;
  grid-gap: 8px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(30%, 1fr));
  */
}

.tag {
  background-color: #2F3841;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: max-content;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="tagsContainer">
  <h3 id="tagsTitle">TOP TAGS</h3>
  <div id="tags">
    <div class="tag">
      <h4 class="tagTitle">Flutter</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="tag">
      <h4 class="tagTitle">Deep Learning</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="tag">
      <h4 class="tagTitle">Machine Learning</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```css
body {
  background: #202223;
}

#tags {
  font-family: cursive;
  width: 292px;
}

.tag {
  font-family: inherit;
  background: #2b333b;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 33px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 16px;
  color: #d4d4d4;
  font-style: italic;
  display: inline-block;
  width: max-content;
  margin: 4px 4px;
}

.tag:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.tag:focus {
  outline: 1px solid #6868688f;
  outline-offset: -3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="tags">
  <button class="tag">Flutter</button>
  <button class="tag">Data Science</button>
  <button class="tag">CSS</button>
  <button class="tag">Deep Learning</button><button class="tag">Machine Learning</button>
</div>
```